# PHP function, needed few input for post_type(wordpress theme function)

Tags: php, wordpress, function

Function within theme function of wordpress

```
function child_post_list($title){
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>1, 'post_type' => 'updatelist');
$update_list_post = get_posts( $args ); //UPDATE LIST post
if(isset($update_list_post[0])){
    $args = array('meta_key'=>'_wpcf_belongs_updatelist_id', 'meta_value' => $update_list_post[0]->ID,'post_type' => "'indon-stat';'myanmar-stat'");
    $child_posts = get_posts( $args ); //the child listing of UPDATE LIST post
    foreach($child_posts as $post){
        if(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-biodata-code', true) == $title){ //if the post title is exist within the custom field of the child listing of UPDATE LIST post.
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

}

As you can see, the last part of the code

```
"'indon-stat';'myanmar-stat'");
```

This is definitely wrong syntax, so I would like to ask what is the correct one? And is it even possible to insert more than one post-type for this?

Comment: It depends on your application. You can use array, or commas, or space. But if we don't know enough information, we cannot help.

Comment: edited question, thought I should make it simple, i'm really bad in php

Comment: @AD7six it is not what you said it is, as it is more like retrieving from multiple post types

Comment: Please edit the question - don't write comments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert more than one post types , then try to insert it as comma seperated values or as a JSON string

```
'post_type' => "indon-stat,myanmar-stat"
```

Comment: Conditional expression includes illegal characters